# How can we hide the information like authentication credentials while passing from UI to backend servers?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, microservices

We are building a mid-sized project. We have React UI and Express backend. For authentication, when user submits his credentials, there is a POST call to backend to authenticate user.

The problem is, we can clearly see the user input in-network calls. This might be a problem. Is there a way to hide this information? How is the industry tackling this situation? Is this fine? I've seen Twitter's authentication flow. It's a bit different. I'm unable to see the data I submitted.

Answer (score 2):

It's completly normal to have an POST request with a content of

```
{
   username: "myName123",
   password: "myPassword456"
}
```

You can see this in almost every service, which requires authentication.
When you do this, make sure your communication with the client is encrypted (HTTPS) so that a man in the middle can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't trust the user - clean the input from stuff that should not be there.
2. Encode / hash the input by adding something to mix up the logic.
3. Decode / dehash and verify.

When you encode something with built in feature - like base64 then add some variable to the string that makes it more random.